# How to get random n records for each group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, limit

I am trying to extract n random records for each group in my database.

| User | Data |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | data_User1_1 |
| user1 | data_User1_2 |
| user1 | data_User1_3 |
| user1 | data_User1_4 |
| user1 | data_User1_5 |
| user2 | data_User2_1 |
| user2 | data_User2_2 |
| user3 | data_User3_1 |
| user3 | data_User3_2 |
| user3 | data_User3_3 |
| user3 | data_User3_4 |

And I am trying to retrieve, for example, two random rows for each user in my table:

| User | Data |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | data_User1_1 |
| user1 | data_User1_3 |
| user2 | data_User2_1 |
| user2 | data_User2_2 |
| user3 | data_User3_1 |
| user3 | data_User3_4 |

I am new to SQL, therefore what I did for now is the following query for each user in my table, as there are not many for now. But I would like to automate this with only one query, if possible.

```
select data
from table 
where user = 'user1'
order by rand()
limit 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by user order by rand()) as rn
   from table
) t where rn <= 2
```